# Execute AQL in AngularJS using $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arangodb

I am working with **FOXX** in ArangoDB as backend, and I am already using a page made with **AngularJS**. I am using `$http` for requests and it works good, but now I need to make a complex query.

I would like to know if it is possible execute a query using Arango Query Language from the page in AngularJS using `$http`.

Answer (score 1):

As `$http` is just an API for making AJAX requests you can just use the HTTP AQL API: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/http/queries/aql-queries/

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8529/_api/cursor', {
  query: `
    FOR doc IN collection
    FILTER doc.color = @color
    RETURN doc
  `,
  bindVars: {color: 'blue'}
})
.then(successCallback);
```

If you want something slightly nicer you can use the `aql` template string handler from the [arangojs](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs) module (which provides the ArangoDB JS driver):

```
var aql = arangojs.aql;
var color = 'blue';
$http.post('http://localhost:8529/_api/cursor', aql`
  FOR doc IN collection
  FILTER doc.color = ${color}
  RETURN doc
`)
.then(successCallback);
```

You could also use the arangojs library directly but keep in mind that `$http` also does the magic necessary to make AngularJS notice asynchronous state changes. If you want to use arangojs directly you'll have to make sure to call `$scope.$apply()` manually.

Comment: Thank you. It works, but I would like to know if I can select the database of the collection, because the url http://localhost:8529/_api/cursor is for the default database _system

Comment: Try using `/_db/yourdb/_api/cursor` instead.

Comment: @HerberColop did my suggestion work? Is there anything you would like me to add to my answer?

Comment: @HerberColop if the suggestion works and there's nothing to add, could you mark the answer as accepted?